# Java RMI random latency in a HPC application

Tags: java, rmi, latency, slowdown

I'm using Java and RMI in order to execute 100k Montecarlo Simulations on a cluster of hundreds of cores.

The approach I'm using is to have a client app that invokes RMI processes and divides simulations on the number of available (RMI) processes on the grid.

Once that the simulations have been run I have to reaggregate results.

The only limit I have is that all this has to happen in less than 500ms.

The process is actually in place **BUT** randomly, from time to time, one of the RMI call takes 200ms more to execute.

I've added loads of logs and timings all over the place and as possible reason I've already discarded:

1) Simulations taking extra time
2) Data transfer (it constantly works, only sometimes the slowdown is verified, and only on a subset of RMI calls)
3) Transferring results back (I can clearly timing how long from last RMI calls return to the end of the process)

The only thing I cannot measure is IF any of the RMI Call is taking extra time to be initialized (and honestly is the only thing I can suppose). The reason of this is that -unfortunately- clocks are not synchronized :(

Is that possible that the RMI remote process got passivated/detached/collected even if I keep a (Remote) reference to it from the client?

Hope the question is clear enough (I'm pretty much sure it isn't).

Thanks a mil and do not hesitate to make more questions if it is not clear enough.

Regards,
Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible that the RMI remote process got passivated/detached/collected even if I keep a (Remote) reference to it from the client?

Unlikely, but possible. The RMI remote process should not be collected (as the [RMI FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#noexit) indicates for VM exit conditions). It could, however, be paged to disk if the OS desired.

Do you have a way to rule out GC calls (other than writing a monitor with JVM TI)?

Also, is your code structured in such a way that you send off all calls from your aggregator asynchronously, have the replies append to a list, and aggregate the results when your critical time is up, even if some processors haven't returned results? I'm assuming that each processor is an independent, random event and that it's safe to ignore some results. If not, disregard.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the reply.

The paging thing is the one that scares me.

Anyway I'm not making use of callbacks and I don't actually know what you mean by "rule out GC calls". I have JVM to print GC activity.

The way it works is that a number of threads are created and each one of them is handling an RMI call. Threads and references to RMI process are initialized off line at start-up time and references kept in the client process so to have hot services ready to run.

Would the call-back approach to be any useful in this case? I will anyway give it a go.

Cheers,
Gio

Comment: One more info here. BAsically if I run 1 thread against one RMI process it works always ok. As soon as I make use of more RMI processes (that means more threads **and sockets**) the delays start to appear. If I make calls to my local env (threads and RMI processes on the same hardware, no delays at all. Socket is my next investigation area, does anyway have a clue?

Comment: If you are printing out GC activity, do you see any correlation between the GC firing and the high latency calls? If not, you've ruled out GC (that's all I meant). The only reason for a call-back approach is to safely ignore the high-latency requests, not to fix them. You could still have your answer inside your required timeframe because you'd have your aggregator work off the clock, not off the whims of whatever causes this latency. Since you described your application as a Monte Carlo Sim, I offered is as a possibility (contrast to branch-and-bound, where correctness requires all complete).

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with issue. Basically after insuring that the stub wasn't getting deallocated and that the GC wasn't triggered behind the scene, I used wireshark for understanding if there was any network issue.

What I found out it was that randomly one of the packet got lost and TCP needed on our network 120ms (41 retransmission) for correctly re-transfer data.

When switching to jdk7, SDP and infiniband, we didn't experience the issue anymore.

So basically the answer to my question was... PACKET LOST!

Thanks who replied to the post it helped to focus on the right path!

Gio

Comment: SDP is deprecated and OFED no more come with SDP support. Hence Java's SDP also fails. Any solutions?